# How to send static HTML to database via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a simple "task list" project right now. I have built the I have so far using jQuery and Javascript to insert/delete/manipulate the "tasks". Because all of the elements are created/removed/changed in the DOM, every time the page is refreshed, all changes to the list are lost. I dont want to use a caching system because the aim is to create a system that can be accessed from multiple devices. I would like to set up some sort of PHP database that would allow me to create user profiles and have each users "tasks" separated.

I am familiar with Wordpress so I'm thinking I could use that and its user profile system to accomplish what I need. The issue I have is that I cant find any information as to how I could send the changes that were made to the DOM to a separate database entry associated with each user.

My strategy from there (unless anyone could suggest a better method of storing the data) would be to essentially make a copy of a set section of the raw HTML and post that to the database entry when the user hits a "save" button. Each time they log in, the most recent HTML would be loaded into the DOM as a starting point. They could then make the changes they desire, hit "save" before leaving the site and the cycle would repeat.

I am new to development side of things, so I could be making this way harder than it needs to be. Any links to topics similar to this, suggestions, advice would be appreciated. Im not asking for an in-depth how-to guide (though that would be nice) but to just be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Try learning PHP and yes, this is a site where help others not develop for them.

Comment: I already know a bit of PHP. Just trying to see if there may be a better way to handle this than what I was thinking.

Comment: Just a tip you probably do not need to send straight up HTML to the database. It makes things ridiculously messy. With PHP you should be able to extract the information you need and simply insert it straight into the DOM. You can prob start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) for learning how to connect to a database with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll poke around there and see if i can get what I need.